# Buffered Reader read certain line and text

Tags: java, bufferedreader, split, file-read

This is my first post, so i'm not sure how things work here.
Basically, i need some help/advice with my code. The method need to read a certain line and print out the text after the inputted text and =

The text file would like

```
A = Ant

B = Bird

C = Cat
```

So if the user it input `"A"` it should print out something like

```
-Ant
```

So far, i manage to make it ignore `"="`  but still print out the whole file

here is my code:

```java
public static void readFromFile() {
    System.out.println("Type in your word");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scanner.next();
    String output = "";
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("dictionary.txt");           
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);            
        String[] fields;
        String temp;
        while((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
            temp = input.trim();
            if (temp.startsWith(input)) {
                String[] splitted = temp.split("=");
                output += splitted[1] + "\n";
            }
        }
        System.out.print("-"+output);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: use `hasNext()` in while loop to determine if you have any more lines left....

Comment: dont use input on while use another new Strin like line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this line is the problem, as it will always be true.

```
if (temp.startsWith(input))
```

You need to have a different variables for the lines being read out of the file and for the input you're holding from the user. Try something like:

```
String fileLine;
while((fileLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        temp = fileLine.trim();
        if (temp.startsWith(input))
        {
            String[] splitted = temp.split("=");
            output += splitted[1] + "\n";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works: STEPS:

1) read `input` using `scanner`
2) read `file` using `bufferedreader`
3) `split` each line using `"-"` as a `delimiter`
4) `compare` `first` character of `line` with `input`
5) `if first character` is equal to `input` then `print the associated value`, `preceded by a "-"`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner; 
class myRead{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Type in your word");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.next();
        long numberOfLines = 0;
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")); 
        String line = myReader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                String[] parts = line.split("=");
                if (parts[0].trim().equals(input.trim())) {
                System.out.println("-"+parts[1]);
                }
                line = myReader.readLine();
            } 
}
}
```

OUTPUT (DEPENDING ON INPUT):

```
- Ant
- Bird
- Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useDelimiter()` method of `Scanner` to split input text

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(.)*="); // Matches 0 or more characters followed by '=', and then gives you what is after `=`
```

The following code is something I've tried in IDEONE (http://ideone.com/TBwCFj)

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        s.useDelimiter("(.)*=");
        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            String ss = s.next();
            System.out.print(ss);

        }
 /**
  * Output
  *
  */
  Ant
  Bat
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first split the text file by new line "\n" (assuming after each "A = Ant", "B = Bird" ,"C = Cat" declaration it starts with a new line) and THEN locate the inputted character and further split that by "=" as you were doing.

So you will need two arrays of Strings (String[ ]) one for each line and one for the separation of each line into e.g. "A" and "Ant".
You are very close.